# iOS scrollsToTop solution when multiple scrollviews exist but only one is set scrollsToTop

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have looked at many of the other similar questions, but don't have a clear answer relevant to iOS6.

I have an app that has screens with two UIScrollView subclasses -- a UICollectionView and a UITableView.   The UITableView is visually underneath/below the UICollectionView, which (collection view) is providing a set of buttons and the UITableView is providing a scrollable list of data.  The request has been made that the tableview scroll to the top if the status bar is touched, like in apps that have one main scrollview derivative that covers the whole screen.

In our case, neither of the two scrollview derivatives cover the whole screen, and the UICollectionView is always scrolled to the top already.

On the UICollectionView scrollsToTop = NO.  On the UITableView scrollsToTop is set to YES.  The views are siblings in the view hierarchy.

I have seen mentioned in other questions one solution of putting a transparent view over the status bar and intercepting touch events, but that there were some side effects with that.

Another solution was to observe a system notification "_UIApplicationSystemGestureStateChangedNotification".  This kind of looks like a private Apple notification and I am concerned about App Store accessibility doing this.

(Another wrinkle is that there is also a subclass of my class that overlays a child viewcontroller's view on top of the tableView, and it has its own UITableView to display.  In this case, the original root class tableView is set to scrollsToTop = NO and the child viewController's scrollsToTop = YES -- without it working of course).

Is there a general and Apple accepted way to do this?  I was hoping for a documented notification or something along those lines but have not been able to find one.  I'd really like to be able to have this simple functionality of my tableView responding as people expect when the status bar is touched.